# visualizing ratings with rating bars in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some ratings from 0 to 1 and want to go for five rating bars. The rating bars should represent the ratings.

Here are some examples of what I want to achieve

[image]

[image]

Below these bars I want to show the average and and count of full containers.

So I go for this code

```js
var ratings = [0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.6, 1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 0.6, 0.1, 1, 1];

$(document).ready(function() {
  initializeStatistics();
});

function initializeStatistics() {
  var ratingBarsLength = $(".ratingBar").length;

  var ratingBars = {};

  for (var i = 1; i <= ratingBarsLength; i++) {
    ratingBars[i] = [];
  }

  splitRatings(ratingBars, ratingBarsLength);
  setRatingBars(ratingBars, ratingBarsLength);
  createFinalRatingBar(ratingBarsLength);
}

function splitRatings(ratingBars, ratingBarsCount) {
  ratings.forEach(function(rating) {
    var containerIndex = Math.round(ratingBarsCount * rating);
    ratingBars[containerIndex].push(rating);
  });
}

function setRatingBars(ratingBars, ratingBarsCount) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= ratingBarsCount; i++) {
    var currentBar = $("#ratingBar" + i);
    var barWidth = (ratingBars[i].length / ratings.length) * 100;
    currentBar.width(barWidth + "%");
  }
}

function createFinalRatingBar(ratingBarsLength) {
  var totalRatings = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
    totalRatings += ratings[i];
  }

  var imageCounter = 0;

  for (var j = 0; j < ratingBarsLength; j++) {
    var imageIsFull = j < (totalRatings / ratingBarsLength);
    if (imageIsFull) {
      imageCounter++;
    }
  }

  $("#finalRatingContainer").html("average: " + (totalRatings / ratingBarsLength) + " | containers: " + imageCounter + " full containers");
}
```

```css
.ratingBar {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 30px;
}

#ratingBar1 {
  background-color: #ff6f31;
}

#ratingBar2 {
  background-color: #ff9f02;
}

#ratingBar3 {
  background-color: #ffcf02;
}

#ratingBar4 {
  background-color: #88b131;
}

#ratingBar5 {
  background-color: #99cc00;
}

#finalRatingContainer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="ratingBar5" class="ratingBar"></div>
<div id="ratingBar4" class="ratingBar"></div>
<div id="ratingBar3" class="ratingBar"></div>
<div id="ratingBar2" class="ratingBar"></div>
<div id="ratingBar1" class="ratingBar"></div>

<div id="finalRatingContainer"></div>
```

As you can see the calculation is not correct. The first bar and the second bar have a bigger width than the fourth and fifth bar. But the average is closer to zero than five.

Is my calculation wrong? Are my bars wrong?

When taking a look to the bars the final rating should have an output like

> average: more than 2.5 | containers: 3 full containers

Comment: If the bars represent the number of users who voted a certain range, then this looks like it's working the way it's intended. First bar from the top is the largest because that is the largest number of people who voted 0.9 or 1.0 and so on..

Comment: `Math.round(ratingBarsCount * rating)` is not equally distributed. Is a rating of `0` possible? If `0.1` is the lowest, then this just barely rounds to `1`, instead of `0`. Try `Math.ceil(ratingBarsCount * rating)` instead, if `0` is not a valid rating. This is equally distributed.

Comment: Shouldn’t the average calculation be `(totalRatings * ratingBarsLength / ratings.length)`? Or `(totalRatings * ratingBarsLength / ratings.length).toFixed(2)`? I’m not sure what “full containers” means.

Comment: @Xufox yes a rating of 0 is possible. I went for your suggestion `(totalRatings * ratingBarsLength / ratings.length)` this seems to be better I hope

Comment: A rating from 0 to 1, _both_ inclusive is a little trickier, though.

Comment: so you think `(totalRatings * ratingBarsLength / ratings.length)` is not correct?